# Too many dovecot process : checkpassword-reply

Tags: process, cpanel, whm, dovecot

everyone.

I have a server with this specs:

24 cores.
32Gb RAM
4Tb Disk Space.

But to weeks ago I have an issue, the server is high load. By filtering the processes I can see that the process that is most repeated is:

/usr/local/cpanel/bin/dovecot-wrap /usr/libexec/dovecot/checkpassword-reply

The last time there was a high load, there were more than 500 queuing processes of this type. I had to kill them all so that the server again had a stable charge. What is happening? I have already reviewed that they are not attacks. I have on this server more than 1100 client accounts and there are more than 4000 domains in it.

This was not happening a month ago. Everything went from one day to another. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest taking this to [sf] because it's really more of a server admin problem than a programming question and you can expect better answers there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a lot of reasons. You have to check the server logs especially dovecot log. Check exim logs as well and you can also take a look of the apache error_log (*/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log*).

That looks like a brute force attack. You can also ask this question on the cPanel forums (since you have a WHM active license you also have support included). From my experience, 1100 cPanel accounts on a server is way too much and that could lead to regular high loads on your server.

I would suggest you install CSF Firewall. In case you have it installed already be sure that you have configured these CSF options:

```
- LF_SMTPAUTH
- LF_DISTATTACK 
- LF_DISTSMTP
- LF_DISTSMTP_UNIQ
- LF_DISTSMTP_PERM
```

Please also check cPhulk (WHM's brute force daemon) configuration to be sure that it's blocking the attacker(s) ip addresses.

Comment: Thank you, Bogdan. I'll check and reply in any case.